# Onclick property conflict with jqueryui drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, onclick

I have an html control with two operation:
1- it has an Onclick function and when Onclick occur an asp.net post back triggers and a modal box for editing open.
2- when I drag it from one html container to another one using jquery ui Drag and Drop, I want onclick not occur and Only drop to another container.

How can I do this? when I want click to drag my control, onclick function called :(

here is my html control:

```
<div class="fc-event fc-event-hori fc-event-draggable fc-event-start fc-event-end event-blue ui-draggable" onclick="CallPostBack('2|NoDate|4');" style="position: relative;"><div class="fc-event-inner"><span class="fc-event-title">aaa</span></div></div>
```

and this is my CallPostBack Javascript function:

```
function CallPostBack(eventArguments) {
    __doPostBack('<%=ctl1.UniqueID %>', eventArguments);
}
```

and here is my functions for drag and move:

```
  function setMovableEvents() {
    //alert('drag');

    return $(".fc-event").each(function () {
        return $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: false,

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: For your first operation which event trigger for click action? onclick or submit?

Comment: @Hughan : I think Onclick  trigger, I set onclick="CallPostBack('2|NoDate|4');" for this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can solve my problem with change My movable Function :

```
  function setMovableEvents() {
    //alert('drag');

    return $(".fc-event").each(function () {
        return $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: false,
            start: function (event, ui) {
                Moving = true;
                $(this).css('z-index', 100000);
                $(this).prop('onclick', '');
            },
            stop: function () {
                Moving = false;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

now when Dragging occur , I clear Onclick to prevent from clicking onclick javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use mouseup instead of click in your jquery:

```
$('.fc-event').mouseup(function(){
    ...
});
```